# Matching pointcuts with specific arguments

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcuts

In Spring, I want an expression that matches a method with specific arguments.

Right now I have this expression

```
     execution(* delete(..))
```

But I want to match specific arguments since there are 4 delete methods in the particular class I am interested in.

I want something like this

```
       execution(* delete(com.xyz.A, com.xyz.B,java.lang.String )
```

This is what I wrote and is not working. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax looks correct.  I believe you are missing a closing parenthesis.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* delete(com.xyz.A, com.xyz.B,java.lang.String))")
```

The reason that it is probably not so obvious is that it is a part of the `String` of your `Pointcut` annotation (assuming you are using the annotation based approach), and so if your IDE of choice does not validate `Pointcut` annotations, it won't throw a big red squiggly in your face.

Comment: I use it from the xml file..not annotations

Comment: Regardless, your pointcut expression is missing a closing parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I do it the following way:

```
@Pointcut("target(com.xyz.ClassName) && execution(* myMethod(com.xyz.A, com.xyz.B,java.lang.String))")
```

Hope it helps.